# Wordpress mysqld has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, crash, cpu

I have wordpress with thousands of catgories/custom taxonomies and tens of thousands of posts.
I have a hard time keeping it online without cache, because processor reaches 100%  ( used by mysql server not php ).

I have isolated a problem, due to mysql update, 
WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]
UPDATE `wphn_options` SET `option_value` =  ...........  ' WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules', this is executed on every page load.

This is an example of that the option_value looks like: `WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away] ( this is not every 1% of the query, just a short preview).

Anyone know how i can stop this query from executing?

```
UPDATE `wphn_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:7269:{s:18:\"sitemap_trolio.xml\";s:33:\"index.php?aiosp_sitemap_path=root\";s:29:\"sitemap_trolio_(.+)_(\\d+).xml\";s:71:\"index.php?aiosp_sitemap_path=$matches[1]&aiosp_sitemap_page=$matches[2]\";s:23:\"sitemap_trolio_(.+).xml\";s:40:\"index.php?aiosp_sitemap_path=$matches[1]\";s:34:\"sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the content of that update to the `options` table, you can see it's related to the sitemap of your site. You may have a sitemap plugin. That sitemap plugin may do something on every page load. Try disabling it.

If you have access to phpmyadmin, first make a backup of your installation and database (if you aren't doing so already).  Then issue the SQL command `OPTIMIZE TABLE wphn_options;` and see if it helps.  If it does, great. Try optimizing some of the other tables as well. `OPTIMIZE TABLE wphn_posts;` might be a good one to try.

But look:  **Your WordPress installation is underprovisioned.** You need better server resources. You've gone to the trouble of creating tens of thousands of posts. By using such a weak server configuration, you are intentionally concealing those posts from your audience, just to save a few coins.

And, you're running the risk of corrupting your site by using a weak server. Is this not the very definition of "penny wise, pound foolish?"

Your question is like "My car's battery is low. I want to stop wasting electricity on my brake lights. Please tell me how to cut the wires to the brake lights."  With respect, the only rational answer is "Are you crazy? You'll risk smashing your car to avoid fixing your battery? Fix your battery!"

Comment: I understand your point of view, but it's not like that at all. I have a dedicated server with 4x Xeon ( Sixcore each). 256 gb RAM, and Samsung SSD hdds, it usually stays at 10% or under, but when the cache is not built is crashes. I have removed AIOSP that was appending to the long update query but the query is still there, it's just shorter, here is a sample of the new query after i removed the sitemap part: __u=1&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]\";s:10:\"^u/(.*)?/?\";s:32:\"index.php?__u=1&name=$matches[1]\";s:14:\"^actor/(.*)?/?\";s:27:\"index.php?actor=$matches[1]\";s:16:\"^regizor/(.*)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, it seems that because of the large number of posts and categories the query could not be built and mysql server crashed to protect it's self.

I have fixed the issue by adding max_allowed_packet=256M in the MySQL configuration file